# galetahub ckeditor with rails 4 layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, paperclip

I improved my ckeditor and added image upload functionality. However, when I try to import an image, I see in the logs that it uses my standard layout, but I'm under the admin namespace, and must use admin layout for this gem...

```
gem 'paperclip'

rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
```

Is it possible to change the layout from standard application to admin for picture uploading? And how?

here it is:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: anybody know how to go?

Comment: How do you mean? Can you provide your relevant source code?

Comment: @JacobEvanShreve what do you mean? i mean how to use gem files like in devise generate them to app (controller) and then change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange, but i delete all gem's from machine, and reinstall them. Trouble was in that, that layout was: application, not ckeditor/application, which is introduced in gem of version 4.0.10, as describen here:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/302

system for some reason get old layout, and that was problem...

now i have some new problems with devise and ckeditor, but not here )

Answer (score 2):

The CKEditor gem doesn't currently allow public configuration of layout. You can override their setting by monkey patching the class, however.

```
# config/initializers/ckeditor.rb

# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
    # configuration goes here
end

# append this after setup block
Ckeditor::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  layout "admin"
end
```

Comment: hm, could not start webrck with this: `# Use this hook to configure ckeditor `# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
if Object.const_defined?("Ckeditor")
  Ckeditor.setup do |config|

    require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"


  end
end
Ckeditor::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  layout "admin"
end
`

Comment: even, if i put this to initializer/my.rb
`Ckeditor::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  layout "admin"
end
Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController.class_eval do
  layout "admin"
end
Ckeditor::PicturesController.class_eval do
  layout "admin"
end`
i get nothing, server start's, but on image server explore - still application.layout

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more explicit. 
Also, you don't need to repeat  the block for the two other controllers, as they inherit from Ckeditor::ApplicationController.